# Postgres FDW connectivity issue from Azure RDS to AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, azure, greenplum, postgres-fdw

I was using FDW extension in PostgreSQL from 2 years to load data from one database to another database. Now, one of my RDS has been moved from AWS to Azure. Now, when I tries to make connection from Azure to AWS it says the host is invalid. So, in this case FDW doesn't works if the RDS are from different service?

Error:

````
  Detail: could not connect to server: Network is down (0x00002742/10050)
    Is the server running on host "xxxxx" (10.xx.xx.xx) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Network is down (0x00002742/10050)
    Is the server running on host "xxxxx" (10.xx.xx.xx) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Network is down (0x00002742/10050)
    Is the server running on host "xx" (10.xx.xx.xxx) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Network is down (0x00002742/10050)
    Is the server running on host "xx" (10.xx.xx.xx) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?```
````

Comment: Do you use host name or ip?

Comment: Either you are using the wrong address, or there are firewalls that prevent the connection. Try using the public address, which won't start with 10.